# Generate report in JasperServer via REST in jrprint format

Tags: rest, jasperserver

Working with jasperserver 4.7.0. Using the REST API (rest_v2), I want to generate a report in jrprint format. After JasperServer's documentation, this is the URL I have to use:

> http://:/jasperserver[-pro]/rest_v2/reports/path/to/report.*format?arguments*
>   where *format* is one of the following: html, pdf, xls, rtf, csv, xml, jrprint

After having properly configured a report in my JasperServer instance, I call the URL following the instructions, like so (for a PDF):

`http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/test/example.pdf`

And it works fine.
However, if I change the format to JRPRINT:

`http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/test/example.jrprint`

then I get a 404 (Not Found) error!

The suffix "jrprint" is correct because if I use any other (invented) one, I get a 400 (Bad request) error.

So the question is: do I have to configure anything special in the JasperServer engine in order to serve JRPRINT reports? Or is there anything I must take into account when placing the call from the client browser?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I'm afraid not. We have decided to generate reports in PDF format, which works perfectly. Guess this is a bug of Jasperserver?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/test/example.jrprint
```

As you said, you get a "404 (Not Found)". But, right after that, try this:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/test/example.jasperPrint
```

And now you should get "200 (OK)", andt the JasperPrint data in the body.
I do not understand why, but this worked for me with JasperServer ver. 5.0.0.